# Save Javascript variable to PHP variable? GET, POST, COOKIE

Tags: php, javascript, database, variables

I want to save `cnt1` and `tim` into MySql database. I understand that Javascript is the client side while PHP is the server side and the available options are to use the `POST GET` and `COOKIE` method. But I can't seem to apply in my code.

It is actually a memory game from http://www.hscripts.com/scripts/jquery/memory-game.php, to play the game the link is http://www.hscripts.com/scripts/jquery/memory-game.php. I want to save the time taken and number of moves.

Any advice? Please and thank you very much.

```
function finish()
{

var cnt1 = $("#counting").val();

var tim=$("#timecount").val();

alert("Congratulations! You have won the game Total Move : "+cnt1+"   Time : "+tim+" seconds");

    if(confirm("Do you want to play again"))
    {
        stopCount();
        window.location.href="index.php";
    }
    else
    {
        window.location.href="leaderboard.php";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just sent them over to php page by concatenating in url

```
if(confirm("Do you want to play again"))
    {
        stopCount();
        window.location.href="index.php?cnt1="+cnt1+"&time="+tim;
    }
    else
    {
        window.location.href="leaderboard.php?cnt1="+cnt1+"&time="+tim;
    }
```

and access on php page as

```
$_GET['tim'];
$_GET['cnt1'];
```

Comment: cannot. ): I am using this http://www.hscripts.com/scripts/jquery/memory-game.php codes if you are willing to help me look at the whole codes.

Comment: Hey it works somehow after i changed the codes here and there! Thankyou for suggesting concatenating into url.. it makes my life so so much easier! Thanksss! You guys who respond to questions are simply awesome!